# Why is my mouse putting my laptop to sleep?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, mouse, sleep, power-management

I run Windows 10 on a Thinkpad P50. A Logitech G300s mouse is plugged in.

The mouse seems to put the latop to sleep, why?

The power plan is such that the laptop never sleeps when plugged in (sleeps after 15 min when on battery). Despite that, it goes to sleep after a few minutes. The mouse is blank (it has LEDs on the side) and when clicked, wakes the laptop up.

**Is it possible that a mouse triggers the sleep function of a laptop? Maybe when not used for some time?**

I went though all Windows 10 settings I could think of (particularly the power plan) and the Logitech "companion software" which configures the mouse but there was nowhere a hint of such functionality.

Comment: “The power plan is such that the laptop never sleeps” – but is it? Please check. Another power plan could be active. Also, are you sure it’s not just the screen turning off? And no, a mouse cannot do that.

Comment: @DanielB: yes, the right power plan is enabled. No, this is not only the screen turning off (which by the way is set at 10 minutes, while the sleep happens after a few minutes). As whether the mouse can do that: this is  a gaming mouse with some intelligence built in (storage capabilities for instance) which talks to a software running on the PC (the "companion software") so this channel is not improbable. But if you are sure that this is technically impossible then I will look further in in the settings (and switch mouses for a moment to check this out with a different mouse)

Comment: I don't think it's the mouse. 2 reasons: I have a similar setup and the same mouse and I never came across this problem, also clicking the mouse (or moving it or touching the touchpad) is a method of coming out of the sleep mode.